# import RelatedManager from django.db.models.fields.related

Tags: django, django-managers

I'm trying to do this:

```
from django.db.models.fields.related import RelatedManager
```

because I want to be able to test if an object is a related manager ie:

```
isinstance(obj, RelatedManager)
```

however I keep getting this error:
Error: cannot import name RelatedManager

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The related manager classes are created at runtime inside generator functions in django.db.models.fields.related thus you can't import them directly.  If you want to check if an object is a related manager for a specific relation you can use `isinstance(obj, MyModel.my_relation.__class__)`.  You could also use `hasattr` to determine if the object has the properties you need (ducktyping) and avoid using isinstance altogether.